# Query Wordpress Database outside of Wordpress blog to return latest blog link, excerpt

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am in the process of writing some php to query my wordpress blog database and display the latest post on my homepage which is outside the wordpress environment.

I am not very well-versed in php but i have been able to display the latest blog title, as well as the post content. What I would like to do is have the thumbnail be a clickable link to the post. How do i get the link to the post?  I also want to display just the excerpt not the entire post-however using post_excerpt in the same fashion as i have with post_title, post_content, does not seem to work.

```
// ...Connect to WP database
$dbc = mysql_connect(XXX,XXX,XXX);
if ( !$dbc ) {
    die( 'Not Connected: ' . mysql_error());
}
// Select the database
$db = mysql_select_db('wrd_2ikhd5ho53');
if (!$db) {
    echo "There is no database: " . $db;
}


  // ...Formulate the query
$query = "
        SELECT post_title,post_content,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_date) AS post_date_unix, ID
        FROM `wp_posts`
        WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'
        AND `post_password` = ' '
        AND `post_type` = 'post'
        ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_date` DESC
        ";

// ...Perform the query
$result = mysql_query( $query );

// ...Check results of the query and terminate the script if invalid results
if ( !$result ) {
    $message = '<p>Invalid query.</p>' . "\n";
    $message .= '<p>Whole query: ' . $query ."</p> \n";
    die ( $message );
}

// Init a variable for the number of rows of results
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $result );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC );

// Init var for DATE of the post
$post_date = date( "l, F jS, Y ", $row['post_date_unix'] );  

// Init var for TITLE of the post
$post_title = $row['post_title'];

// Init var for CONTENT of the post
$post_content = $row['post_content'];
$post_excerpt = $row['post_excerpt'];

// Init var for Excerpt of the post

// Print the number of posts
echo "$post_title";
echo "$post_date";



// Free the resources associated with the result set
if ( $result ) {
    mysql_free_result( $result );
    mysql_close();
}


?>
```

the website to reference is http://www.uniconutrition.com

Thanks guys

Answer (score 6):

It can be much easier than what you're trying by using the **WordPress database layer**. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Basically:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=1');
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Or, **there is always RSS** to grab one item, title and excerpt from WordPress.

**[Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/feed/)**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://fastpshb.appspot.com/feed/1/fastpshb");
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("feed");
          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
            container.appendChild(div);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="feed"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This slows my site down too much :( thats why im futzing with querying the database myself

Comment: Wow, if that slows your site down, you have other, more serious issues with the host. What about RSS?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with RSS to say the least- in the code above would i simply input the my blog url where it says '..fastpshb...' ? And ya it really slowed my pagespeed down--others have said it makes sense because that php loads the entire wordpress environment..

Comment: Read the docs on how to use the Google RSS API. As for "others have said it makes sense because that php loads the entire wordpress environment", that makes no sense at all. Your host - eigbox.net, pow web, whoever it really it - is well known as a crappy host, and that's why something as simple as WP loads down your account.

Comment: i use ipage- can you reccommend a better host?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as the excerpt is concerned, you aren't `SELECT`ing it in your query. Change the beginning of your query to:

```
SELECT post_title, post_content, post_excerpt,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_date) AS post_date_unix, ID
```

As for the link to the post, I'm not 100% sure you can get a "pretty-printable" link without going through the WordPress machinery. A short-link style URL is available under the `guid` column in the `wp_posts` table, but the WP docs claim that it may not show up if pretty permalinks are disabled. Since you know the ID of the post (it's a part of your query), you could just use the WordPress functions to get the link. See the [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink) documentation page for more.

As an aside, have a look at [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as a replacement for the `mysql_*` functions. You should no longer use the latter.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback jonah-- as for the ID i just threw that in the query i havent been able to actually get it out though..do i declare a variable like the others? ie $post_id = $row['post_id'];

Comment: Yes, simply create another variable (or you can simply access it through `$row['ID']` if you like). Note that the column name is `ID` and not `post_id`.

Comment: Ok i got it to 'echo' the id...how do i get the permalink form the id?

Comment: do i declare a permalink variable? like $permalink = get_permalink( $id );

Comment: That should do it. When in doubt, try it out!

Comment: does the db know what 'get_permalink' means?

Comment: The `get_permalink` function is a WordPress function, so you need to pull in some of the WordPress environment into your PHP file. See the following link for info on how to do it: [Embed WordPress Functions Outside WordPress](http://wpengineer.com/1038/embed-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress/)

Comment: DOing it that way is the whole reason I'm trying to write my own PHP- because loading the wordpress environment slows my site down enourmously

Comment: i tried 'require' the wordpress link template file that has get permalink in it...but i cant seem to make it work with defining the variable and then 'echo' ing it